# Using puppet third party module

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I installed one module from :

[Puppet Redis Module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/thomasvandoren/redis)

Now I have the directory structure as follows :

[image]

**Contents of g_redis.pp :**

```
class g_redis{
   include redis 

   class {'redis' : 
      version => '2.6.14',
      redis_port => '7000' ----->A
   }

   redis::instance{ 'redis-7000'
      redis_port => '7000', ----->B
   }
}
```

**Contents of site.pp is :**

```
import 'classes/*.pp'

node default{}

node 'nodename'{
    include g_redis
}
```

Now I have questions like  :

1. What is the difference in (A) and (B)
2. The error is coming while running the manifest :
     [image]

Answer (score 1):

- For your first question, `class{'redis':}` will start a default instance, so I think you don't need to instantiate a redis:instance, unless you want to have two different instances running in your box.
- For your second question

```
 include redis 

 class {'redis' : 
    version => '2.6.14',
    redis_port => '7000' ----->A
 }
```

Here you are instantiating twice redis class.

```
   include redis
```

is almost equivalent to

```
   class {'redis' :
   }
```

So second Class['redis'] gives you this error

You should choose between using a basic redis setup or a customized one. If you want two different versions of redis running simultaneously you will have to work hard on the recipes.

- If you want redis 2.6.14 listening on port 7000', all you want is simply:

```
node 'nodename'{
    class{'redis':
       version    => '2.6.14',
       redis_port => '7000'
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how to use this, I am not understanding that, 
OK I installed the redis module,
now how to use that with my class? 
:D

Comment: No. You ALREADY have installed redis puppet module. By doing `class{'redis':}` your *nodename* server will install `redis` package and then start `redis` service with standard settings, so your apps will be able to use it for storing and retrieving things.

Comment: This is the manifests, that is going to be placed in master, and I am going to prepare definitions for nodes(agents), so that redis will start there(in agent), so I want to write my manifests around this redis module in master, for that I wrote this, did I made a mistake

Comment: No, it's the right way, but inside your class `g_redis` you only need a single `class{'redis':}` . No `include` and no additional `redis::instance`

Comment: Ok ok, now I got it, I will try once and come back to mark your answer as accepted. So you have to wait for it. :P :D :), and one more thing thanks for your help.